# How To Set Atom-Beautify Wrap HTML Attribute

Tags: html, atom-editor, js-beautify

I use atom-beautify to format html,but it allways put all the attributes in one line. How can I set atom-beautify to keep attributes  in different lines.

```
<!--What I want-->
<a class="btn btn-default" 
   ng-click="history.more=!history.more">
   More
</a>

<!--The current format result-->
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="history.more=!history.more">
   More
</a>
```

[image: My current HTML config]

Answer (score 5):

```
html_wrap_attributes: "force"
```

It appears your config already has Wrap attributes set to "force", so that should be enough. If not, you can run the atom-beautify debug (Packages->Atom Beautify->Debug) to determine the final combined and transformed options that are used to beautify your html.